# Exp-resso Store Shipping Country being ignored

Tags: expresso-store

I have a store that is doing international shipping. In this store I am giving the option to do international shipping but bill to the US. However, when the billing address is set to the US and the Shipping options are set to another country, I am still getting US billing prices.

What must you do to have the Shipping Region choices override the Billing Region choices?

Brad

Answer (score 1):

In the Store > Settings > General tab scroll down to Default Shipping Address unless you have modified this it will be set to "Shipping Address Same as Billing Address" which means that until you have submitted both a shipping and billing address Store will only use the value of the billing field. From the sounds of it you would want to use "None"

Comment: I have it set to that choice, however they are still ignored. This is in EE 2.5.5 and Store 1.6.3. If you email me directly I can get you access. But, it isn't working. :(

Comment: I just sent you an email